# Mathematica equivalent to HTML `code` or LaTeX `\texttt`

Tags: formatting, fonts

I know in HTML or LaTeX there is a way to easily put a phrase in a `monospace` font. Is there a way to do this in Mathematica without manually changing the font for the words I want in monospace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will depend on what style sheet you use. In the Default style sheet you can select the text and hit the <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> (OS x — I think it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> on Windows).

Here is an example.

[image: text]

Comment: are you sure it's monospaced? Difficult to tell, but the width of the 'S' looks bigger than the one of the 'i'!?

Comment: @M.Stern. Oops, Cmnd+9 or Alt+9. Sorry for the typos.

Comment: `Alt`+`9` worked on Linux